# Export fields from VB.NET to .XLSX

Tags: excel, vb.net, export

I am trying to generate an excel sheet and then export several fields to that sheet, this from VB.NET to Excel.
The detail in my code is that when I try to send it to Excel, it marks me that it cannot open the file and it does not allow me to continue.

Can you please support me? This is my code.

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Core
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
Imports ExcelAutoFormat = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlRangeAutoFormat
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop

Imports DevExpress.Spreadsheet
Imports DevExpress.Spreadsheet.Export

        Using saveDialog As SaveFileDialog = New SaveFileDialog()

            saveDialog.OverwritePrompt = True
            saveDialog.DefaultExt = ".xlsx"
            saveDialog.Filter = "Excel Workbook (.xlsx)|"
            saveDialog.InitialDirectory = "C:\TEMP\"
            saveDialog.AddExtension = True
            saveDialog.FileName = "C:\TEMP\Example.xlsx"

            Dim exportFilePath As String = saveDialog.FileName

            Dim fileExtenstion As String = New FileInfo(exportFilePath).Extension

            GridControl16.ExportToXlsx(exportFilePath)

            If File.Exists(exportFilePath) Then

                Try
                    Dim xlsWorkBook As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook
                    Dim xlsWorkSheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet
                    Dim xls As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application

                    xlsWorkBook = xls.Workbooks(exportFilePath)
                    xlsWorkSheet = xlsWorkBook.Sheets("Sheet1")

                    xlsWorkSheet.Cells(1, 1) = TextBox1.Text

                Catch
                    Dim msg As String = "The file could not be opened." & Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine & "Path: " & exportFilePath
                    MessageBox.Show(msg, "Error!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.[Error])
                End Try
            Else
                Dim msg As String = "The file could not be saved." & Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine & "Path: " & exportFilePath
                MessageBox.Show(msg, "Error!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.[Error])
            End If

        End Using
```

Thank you for your time and help.

Regards.

Comment: Never check `File.Exists()` like that. Just open the file and handle the exception instead if it fails.

Comment: As for the specific question, it would be helpful if you would share the _exact message_. The problem here could range from permissions, to locking, to missing or incorrect version of Excel on the machine. The error message will tell you that, and if you don't share it we can't hope to help you. The fact this isn't already in the question also tells us things about you.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn, thank you for your answer, in the Try Catch send this error: Invalid Index. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800200B (DISP_E_BADINDEX)). Thank you and regards

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn, my system is Windows 10, Visual Studio 2019, Excel v2016 64bit.

Comment: And which line throws that exception?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn, this on: `xlsWorkBook = xls.Workbooks(exportFilePath)`

Comment: You don't have the file opened anywhere else, do you?